# i18n for View Title

Tags: sapui5

I am trzing to use i18n model for my view title but it is not showing correct title. Only variable it is showing.

**

### here are my xml view details :

**

```
<mvc:View
controllerName="sap.ui.demo.myFiori.view.Master"
xmlns="sap.m"
xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" >
<Page
    title="{i18n>MasterTitle}" >
    <List
        items="{/SalesOrderCollection}" >
        <StandardListItem
            type="Active"
            press="handleListItemPress"
            title="{SoId}" />
    </List>
</Page>
```

**

1. below is details from file messageBundle.Properties

**

MasterTitle=Sales Orders
DetailTitle=Sales Order

**

### details of Component.js file are as below :

**

jQuery.sap.declare("sap.ui.demo.myFiori.Component");

sap.ui.core.UIComponent.extend("sap.ui.demo.myFiori.Component", {

```
createContent : function() {

    // create root view
    var oView = sap.ui.view({
        id : "app",
        viewName : "sap.ui.demo.myFiori.view.App",
        type : "JS",
        viewData : { component : this }
    });

    // set i18n model
    var i18nModel = new sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel({
        bundleUrl : "i18n/messageBundle.properties"
    });
    oView.setModel(i18nModel, "i18n");
```

//      // Using OData model to connect against a real service
//      var url = "/proxy/http/:/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZGWSAMPLE_SRV/";
//      var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(url, true, "", "");
//      oView.setModel(oModel);

```
    // Using a local model for offline development
    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("model/mock.json");
    oView.setModel(oModel);

    // done
    return oView;
}
```

});

Output is as below ![enter image description here][1]

In output it is showing MasterTitle instead of Sales Oreders

I want to display Sales Orders instead of MasterTitle in the title of Xml view page

Comment: I tried the same but it is showing MasterTitle onlz instead of Sales Orders

Answer (score 0):

We should always use absolute paths relative to our own component.
Because relative paths will fail if running in the Fiori Launchpad.

```
    var oRootPath = jQuery.sap.getModulePath("sap.ui.demo.myFiori");
    // Set i18n model
    var i18nModel = new sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel({
        bundleUrl : [oRootPath, "i18n/messageBundle.properties"].join("/")
    });
    this.setModel(i18nModel, "i18n");
```

You can put a break model at the last line and check if model holds any data or not.

Comment: I tried the same but it is showing MasterTitle onlz instead of Sales Orders.

Comment: is any data getting bounded to model? what do get in i18nModel before setting the model.

Comment: Before that are you getting oRootPath?
Have you registered your path? jQuery.sap.registerModulePath(sModuleName, sUrlPrefix)